# How can I change only the text inside a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following link which i want to modify its text from "new subsite" to "create new customer site":-

[image]

so i wrote the following jquery :-

```
$('a#createnewsite').text('Create New Customer Site');
```

which replaced not only the text but also the span that contain the "+" image, while i was trying to keep everything except replacing the text.. here is the result after applying the jQuery :-

[image]

Comment: [How to select text nodes with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text nodes can be selected by using [`jQuery.contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) together with  [`jQuery.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
$(function() {
  $("a#createnewsite").contents().filter(function() {
    // filter text nodes that contain one or more non-whitespace characters
    return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && /\S/.test(this.nodeValue);
  }).replaceWith("new text");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="createnewsite" href="#">
  <span>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/64x64/000/fff" width="64" height="64">
  </span>
  new subsite
</a>
```

Comment: I think you meant to type a comparison instead of an assignment

Comment: Your markup probably has whitespace (screenshots do not always help). See revised answer.

Comment: worked well after adding  Node.TEXT_NODE && /\S/.test(this.nodeValue);

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the text node, then change the text of it.

```
$('#createnewsite')
    .contents()
    .filter(function() { return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE; })
    .text('Create New Customer Site');
```

Comment: this did not have any effect on the link